# how to tell if a cell is #NAME?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to avoid errors when executing a vba script so I check the content of the cells before I do something with them.

```
If ((Cells(i, 18).Value > 0) And (Trim(Cells(i, 3).Value) <> "") And (Trim(Cells(i, 4).Value) <> "")) And (Trim(Cells(i, 10).Value) <> "") _
         Then ' Do something
```

It works with empty cells but not with cells the contain 
"#NAME?"

How can I validate that?

Comment: That takes care of #Name error but what would you do if it is a #Div error or Value# error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the `ERROR.TYPE()` worksheet function. This will return 5 is the error is `#NAME`.

If B1 contains your `#NAME` error, then the following would return 5:

```
=ERROR.TYPE(TEXT(B1,""))
```